# A function whose second derivative is zero

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function which is differentiable sufficient number of times on $(a,b)$, $f(a)=0$ and whose first and second left derivatives at $a$ are zero, i.e., $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=0,$$ $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{h}=0$$ and $f''(t)=0$ on $(a,b)$. Then should $f(t)=0$ on $(a,b)$?

Comment: Sorry, I missed $f''(t)=0$ on $(a,b)$. May I edit accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

I recommend trying out this kind of questions in the simplest functions that you know, for example, polynomials. Since you can choose the roots as you see fit.

edited answer: In that case you should integrate to find all the posible solutions to that ordinary differential equation (Dont forget to add the constants) and see how you must choose the constants to make the other condition apply.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. Please look into the edited question.